# Laravel 3 Eloquent How to select column as

Tags: select, laravel, alias, eloquent, laravel-3

I'm trying to figure out how to give a column an alias using Eloquent.

So, in other words, how do I execute the following mysql query using Eloquent?

```
SELECT occupation AS test FROM users WHERE occupation = 'PIMP';
```

Thx in adv!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Eloquent returns a regular Fluent query. So you can try something like this (assuming your model name is 'User'):

```
$user = User::where_occupation('pimp')->get(array('occupation as test'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I have been able to do this in Laravel 5 using `select()` and passing the col name and the alias to that method (here I'm also using `groupby()` to restrict it to "`DISTINCT`" return values then using `toarray()` to return any array instead of a `Collection Object`:

```
$results = asset::select('model_code__c AS option')->whereRAW("model_code__c <> '' AND status = 'A'")->groupby('model_code__c')->get()->toarray();
```